# Mupdf Android make generate not working

Tags: android, git, makefile, mupdf

I can't able to build the mupdf android. I am getting the following error while executing the command make generate

```
make generate
CC build/debug/cmapdump.o
/bin/sh: cc: command not found
Makefile:157: recipe for target 'build/debug/cmapdump.o' failed
make: *** [build/debug/cmapdump.o] Error 127
```

I am using the latest code cloned from git repository. I am using windows 7, with cygwin. When I searched through various forums, they mentioned like its because of missing of c compiler in cuygwin. But I have gcc installed.

Comment: When I tried the same with ubuntu, everything fine and no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem and found the answer in the issues of the mupdf.
http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693935

The solution is to re-run the *cygwin* setup and and select a *C compiler* from the packages list.
I used the gcc compiler from the *Devel* category.